# Objective C: Unable to Assign value to Labels

Tags: objective-c, uilabel, variable-assignment

I am trying to access properties of an object (person's firstName) which is stored in an array and assign it to labels in a seperate view Controller (SplitMethodViewController). The name value is successfully assigned here. Code snippet as below:

In the initial view controller (before displaying the modal view controller containing the UILabel):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    int row = [indexPath row];
    Person *thisPerson = (Person *)[self.personArray objectAtIndex:row];

    SplitMethodViewController *smvc = [[SplitMethodViewController alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    smvc.nameLabel.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", thisPerson.firstName];

    //This lines returns the value I want, showing that assignment is working till this point
    NSLog(@"The name label is %@", smvc.nameLabel.text);

    [self presentModalViewController:smvc animated:YES];

    [smvc release];

}
```

However, the values became blank when I check in the splitMethodViewController (checked in ViewDidLoad Method)

```
@interface SplitMethodViewController : UIViewController 
{
    UILabel *nameLabel;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *nameLabel;
@end

@implementation SplitMethodViewController

@synthesize nameLabel;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
    // Custom initialization.
    self.nameLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)init 
{
    return [self initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
}
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    //name label returning nothing here.
    NSLog(@"namelabel is %@",self.nameLabel.text);

    [super viewDidLoad];
}
@end
```

I am sure I made some silly mistake somewhere. I have tried deleting all the outlets and labels and re-created just one name label and outlet. But I am still hitting this same issue.

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you actually allocate and instantiate the *nameLabel* and *evenBillAmountLabel* once you instantiate the SplitMethodViewController? In Objective-C messages (method calls) can be sent to nil (non-existant objects) without returning any errors, but also without any results.

Make sure the *-init* method on *SplitMethodViewController* looks somewhat like this:

```
// this is the designated initializer of most view controllers, 
// do initialization here ...
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibName bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundle 
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibName bundle:nibBundle]; 
    if (self)
    {
        nameLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        evenBillAmountLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        // add other stuff you need to initialize ...
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)init 
{
    // since we don't wanna re-implement allocation and instantiation for every 
    // initializer, we call the 'designated initializer' with some default values,
    // in this case the default nibName and bundle are nil.
    return [self initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
}

- (void)dealloc 
{
    [nameLabel release];
    [evenBillAmountLabel release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Be sure to read about designated initializers if this is new to you and if this was related to your issue. [Here's a link to Apple's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocAllocInit.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH22-SW4) on the subject.

Comment: thanks for your advise. I followed it and I now have values assigned to the nameLabel. But the strange thing is that the label is still displayed as blank. I have recreated the labels and outlets just to ensure I have not made any silly mistakes. I have updated the code snippet in my original posts. If you can help to take a look again it will be much appreciated! Thanks again for your help

Comment: Do you actually make use of a nib file? Usually I create my ViewControllers completely in code. If you make use of a nib file, you might have to change the designated initializer to make use of the nib. You also might want to set the frames of the labels in code. A label with a frame of CGRectZero (the default) won't show a single line of text. And finally make sure the textColor of the label is in contrast with the background.

Comment: Yes I do use a NIB file. I found the way around my issue, I had to pass the value of the name as a String to my splitMethodViewController first, then set it directly to the label in the splitViewController. Not sure why the initial methods didn't work though.

Answer (score 1):

If Wolfgang's answer doesn't solve it, be sure that your `UILabel` references in your SplitMethodViewController.xib file are wired up to the correct referencing outlet in your SplitMethodViewController.h file.

Comment: Yah, I suspected I made some errors in the IB. So I deleted all the outlets and labels and recreated only the UILabel for name to see if that works, sadly it is still returning me blank. I just can't seem to find the issue....